# forEach no me toma la variable products

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, base-de-datos, foreach

estoy tratando de que me de un bucle de productos pero al pasar la variable del controlador no me la toma y me tira el error de que no esta definida.
Necesitaria que me den una ayuda porque estuve buscando respuestas pero no envcuentro el error. Puede ser una falla con la conexion a la BD?
Muchas gracias de antemano
aqui los codigos:

aqui los codigos

```
EJS:

<% if(products) { %>
                <% locals.products.forEach((product)=> {%>
                <div class="caja-1">
                        <h2>Pedido</h2>
                        <a href="/products/detail/<%= product.id %>">
                            <img src="/images/<%= product.image %>" alt="Foto de Hamburguesa" width="200px">
                        </a>
                </div>
                <div class="descripcion">
                    <h2>Descripción</h2>
                    <p class="burgerName">
                        <%= product.name %>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <%= product.description%>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="precio">
                    <h2>Precio</h2>
                    <p class="price">
                        <%= product.price %>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="cantidad">
                    <h2>Cantidad</h2>
                    <p class="cant">1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="total">
                    <h2>Total</h2>
                    <p class="price">3000$</p>
                    
                   
                </div>

                <% }); %>
                <% }; %>
```

Controlador:

```
const { validationResult } = require("express-validator");

const db = require("../database/models");

const Product = db.Product;


 const productoController = {
 list: async (req, res) => {
 try {
  const products = await db.Product.findAll();
  res.locals.products= products;
  res.render("productCart");
  } catch (error) {
  res.send({ error });
   }
  },
```

Comment: Agrega el error para ver cuál es el problema.

Comment: ReferenceError: E:\Escritorio\Programacion\clone proyecto\equipo2_Scooby\views\productCart.ejs:10
    8|                 <h1 class="pedidoTitulo">Mis pedidos</h1>
    9|                 <section class="pedidos">
 >> 10|                     <% if(products) { %>
    11|                     <% locals.products.forEach((product)=> {%>
    12|                     <div class="caja-1">
    13|                             <h2>Pedido</h2>

products is not defined